# Follow thread of conversation in which you are not participating

Tags: feature-request, notifications

I receive emails from serverfault with the open questions which I occasionally open and try to answer.

Sometimes there is a question to which I don't have an answer, but I'd like to follow the conversation as someone may post a solution. Unless you make a posting you can't click on the 'notify' checkbox.

The only other way is to leave the thread open in the browser and refresh it every now and again.

Can anything be done to enable this type of functionality? Is there already something there which I've missed

Answer (score 9):

You can click on the star below the voting tabs. This will make it a favourite and you will get notifications in your SE inbox when answers are added to the question etc.

Comment: I think this one should go into the FAQ of StackExchange sties, every one of them.

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore. I tested it by adding a few new unanswered questions to my favorites. I can see that one of them received an answer five hours ago, but I did not receive any notification of that.