# how to subscribe to questions on server fault which I did not asked

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Follow thread of conversation in which you are not participating](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1305/follow-thread-of-conversation-in-which-you-are-not-participating)

There are some good discussions many a times I come across on serverfault and like on other forums I can subscribe to those thread is there a similar option to subscribe them.Until now what I do is in vi I copy paste the link which is interesting to me for my future use.

Comment: @Mark Henderson can you give me a link?

Comment: Have a look at your question, it's been edited into the top of the post